# X-Cart 5.3.1.3 issue

Tags: php, content-management-system, x-cart

Hello I need help in some x-cart issue. What I want to do is to change the city field in the checkout menu from input text into a drop-down and populate the  option with data from database. I'm new in X-Cart and I'm using 5.3.1 version.

Comment: Please give your code, where is the exact issue and what you'd tried.

Comment: The issue is the fact that i don't understand how x-cart works and i need some advices in order to do this particular task.

Comment: The  OOP X-Cart 5 architecture implies that you create a module to override the default behaviour: make a list of cities, tie the cities with the states, make JS on checkout, address book and AOM take it into account. 

Since you don't understand how X-Cart 5 works, you should either start from studying the developer documentation/webinars/tutorials here: http://devs.x-cart.com/ or hire a professional developer for this particular task.

I'm afraid you're requesting not a piece of advice, but the entire code for a particular modufication, this is hardly a format of Stackoverflow Q&A.